# Godot 4 cannot use numpy in an virtual environment for python, reimports all the time

Tags: pandas, numpy, godot, python-venv, godot4

I'm basically building a GUI app in Godot 4, which uses a python script in the background to do some things. It passes variables from Godot to the script with arg-parse. To do these things, I created a Virtual Environment in the File System of Godot. Something similar shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2MHuWEDUNw&ab_channel=ACB_Gamez). (res:// -> Python_files -> venv). The python script that I am using needs pandas to work. Pandas needs numpy. Therefore I pip installed numpy into the venv. Upon switching back to Godot, this is what it looked like:
[Picture of Errors and (re)import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrjVC.png)
Godot keeps re-importing parts of the numpy library, all the time, showing the "(re)import-popup window, and cluttering the venv with umath-validation files (in markdown)

```
Error importing 'res://PythonFiles/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-cos.csv'.
  Error importing CSV translation: expected 3 locale(s), but the '## +ve denormals ##' key has 0 locale(s).
  Error importing 'res://PythonFiles/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-exp.csv'.
  Error importing CSV translation: expected 3 locale(s), but the '## +ve denormals ##' key has 0 locale(s).
  Error importing 'res://PythonFiles/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-log.csv'.
  Error importing CSV translation: expected 3 locale(s), but the '## +ve denormals ##' key has 0 locale(s).
  Error importing 'res://PythonFiles/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-sin.csv'.
```

Even a new **empty Godot project** without any code, gives the same errors.
Following these steps will most likely lead to the same outcome, as my code shows:

1. Create an empty Godot project.
2. Create a new venv in the File System, (new_godot_project -> python_files ->*create venv here*
3. activate the venv and pip install the numpy library.
4. The Popup should appear.

Ubuntu Version 22.04 (also tried on Mac-OS 13.xx)
Python Version 3.10
Godot Version 4.1.1

To solve this problem, I tried different versions of Numpy which are compatible with Pandas, it did not resolve anything.
I also tried the same process on a mac. Still no difference.

I assume that there must be a compatibility problem between Godot and numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add your Python code et.al. to the Godot project. You don't need your external programs to be in `res://` to work. In fact, it is a bad idea.

Launching an executable form `res://` will work when you are launching your application from the editor, but when the application is exported, `res://` does not map to the project folder anymore, instead it maps to a virtual path inside a `.pck` file, and your OS won't be able to launch anything from there (and that is assuming they are there, which requires to import them, and export them - which is possible, but a waste of effort).

*I would suggest to use `user://`, as they are guaranteed to work on the exported application, regardless of operating system. However, that does not make testing and deployment easy.*

See [File paths in Godot projects](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/io/data_paths.html).

---

*For other people reading this…*

Notice that [`OS.execute`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-execute) does not require an absolute path. As long as the OS can resolve the name of what you are trying to execute, it should work.

I also want to mention that it is also possible to launch another program using [`OS.create_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-create-process), or even [`OS.shell_open`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-shell-open), but only `OS.execute` will let you get the `stdout` and `stderr`.

---

The approach I've taken for non-game applications made in Godot is to figure out the path of your Godot application in the system and use that:

```
if OS.has_feature("template"):
    var current_path := OS.get_executable_path().get_base_dir()
```

The call [`OS.has_feature`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-has-feature)`("`[`template`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/export/feature_tags.html)`")` will return `true` if the application is exported. In which case [`OS.get_executable_path`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-executable-path)`().`[`get_base_dir`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-get-base-dir)`()` will be the folder where the application is stored (if the application is not exported - i.e. running from the editor - it will be the folder of the Godot executable, which presumably you don't want to use).

Ok, but how do you test from the editor? One option is to hard-code the path, but barring that, you might resolve the project folder:

```
var current_path := ""
if OS.has_feature("template"):
    current_path = OS.get_executable_path().get_base_dir()
else:
    current_path = ProjectSettings.globalize_path("res://sub_folder/")
```

Here [`ProjectSettings.globalize_path`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-method-globalize-path) translates "res://" and "user://" paths to OS paths.

Ah, but I said to not add your Python code to the Godot project! *But I didn't say to not put it in the project folder.* To do that, you can add a `.gdignore` so the Godot does not include anything inside of that folder to the project. See [Project organization](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/best_practices/project_organization.html).

*Automating the deployment of said folder is another matter, I suggest you use shell script that calls Godot via [command line](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/command_line_tutorial.html) to export the application, and also copies the necessary files.*

---

Barring that, you could always have a way to configure the path. For example, you might have a config file in `user://` (created by the application if it does not exist) where you store the external path you will use, and offer UI to the user to configure it.